# How to automatically index DataFrame created from groupby in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Using the Kiva Loan_Data from Kaggle I aggregated the Loan Amounts by country. Pandas allows them to be easily turned into a DataFrame, but indexes on the country data. The reset_index can be used to create a numerical/sequential index, but I'm guessing I am adding an unnecessary step. Is there a way to create an automatic default index when creating a DataFrame like this?

[image: DataFrame From Groupby Pandas Index Reset]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `as_index=False`
[`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby)
[split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation)

```
df.groupby('country', as_index=False)['loan_amount'].sum()
```